# Gitlab: Pipeline Issue

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I had made a commit in the GitLab branch, then merged it into the `main` branch, but the `.gitlab-ci.yml` pipeline is not updating the last committed code into the production server.

Note: Pipeline is working, but committed changes are not visible.

Comment: After merged the code you saw pipeline running? Are you sure that the pipeline is correct? Can you add more information?

Answer (score 0):

Depend on your version of GitLab, it could be an older bug.

For instance, [`gitlab-org/gitlab-runner` issue 4587](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/-/issues/4587) "GitlabRunner does not check out the latest commit but the previous one"

In your `gitlab-ci.yml`, check what

> Workaround:
>
> have same problem, but if use checkout & pull - everything ok
>
> ```
> git checkout -f $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME && git pull
> ```

As in, for instance:

```yaml
 script:
    - echo $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME
    - git checkout $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME
    - git pull
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.
Try turning off the cache in your pipeline and see once

```
- cache:
```